# Lenovo Yoga Book with Android - which apps can use the drawing pad? (besides Note Saver)

Tags: android, drawing, tablet, sketch

I have Lenovo Yoga Book Android tablet, which has a touch-keyboard, which can turn into Wacom-like drawing pad.

It's amazing, it can even open 360 deg. and be used as a Wacom-like sketch pad, without the display, and it saves the drawing using the app Note Saver.

Now, because of Corona, I would like to use it to draw on meetings, instead of a whiteboard.

[image]
That can be done on the display even with the stylus. But the sensitivity is not as good as with the pad - sometimes, when writing fast, it misses some strokes.

Is there any other application which can make use of this drawing surface?

Answer (score 0):

I figured out.

Initially, the pad does not work. And I thought that Note Saver is the only app capable of working with it, because activating the drawing pad by the hw "button" with a pen icon opens the Note Saver.

However, when I press the pen icon, which activates Note Saver "picture-in-picture" small window, then I need to draw a bit, and then close and dismiss Note Saver (by pressing "LATER").

Then, the pen is active and I can draw with it on any app just like with a finger, and some support pressure sensitivity.